# How to properly quit WebDriver after completing all UI tests with Cucumber

Tags: groovy, selenium-webdriver, gradle, cucumber

We are using Selenium WebDriver to do UI testing, along with Cucumber. The language is Groovy, and the build tool is Gradle. Because it is expensive to create a WebDriver instance, we want to instantiate only one WebDriver instance and use it through all tests. However, we are having trouble to quit the driver properly after all tests are completed. Namely, the browser process spawned during the tests is still alive after running all the tests.

The code is currently structured like below.

```
// Test base class
class UITestBase {
    WebDriver driver

    static {
        init()
    }

    static void init() {
        // instantiate a webdriver
    }
}

// Entry class of cucumber run
RunWith( Cucumber )
Cucumber.Options(...)
class CukeRunEntry {}

// Cucumber step class
class WhenSteps extends UITestBase {
    @When(/^something happens$/)
    void something_happens() {
        // step implmentation
    }
}
```

So, how can I call `driver.quit()` after all tests are finished but before gradle finishes the test task (we run the tests with `./gradlew test` from command line)? I tried overriding the `finalize()` method, but that didn't help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I would prefer using `SharedDriver` that you can find here => https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java

It makes life easier.

**Edit**
If you don't wish to use `SharedDriver`, you can add a block like below to the `UITestBase` class as illustrated in the question:

```
private static final Thread CLOSE_THREAD = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            driver.quit()
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
        }
    }
}

static {
    init()
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(CLOSE_THREAD)
}
```

The above code is essentially what's used in SharedDriver to ensure safe close of the WebDriver instance.

Comment: @JBT has been kind enough to provide an alternative in "Edit" and it is useful and working.